# Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to highlight exactly what changed between two dataframes.

Suppose I have two Python Pandas dataframes:

```
"StudentRoster Jan-1":
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 He was late to class
112  Nick   1.11                     False                Graduated
113  Zoe    4.12                     True       

"StudentRoster Jan-2":
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 He was late to class
112  Nick   1.21                     False                Graduated
113  Zoe    4.12                     False                On vacation
```

My goal is to output an HTML table that:

1. Identifies rows that have changed (could be int, float, boolean, string)
2. Outputs rows with same, OLD and NEW values (ideally into an HTML table) so the consumer can clearly see what changed between two dataframes:

   ```
   "StudentRoster Difference Jan-1 - Jan-2":  
   id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
   112  Nick   was 1.11| now 1.21       False                Graduated
   113  Zoe    4.12                     was True | now False was "" | now   "On   vacation"
   ```

I suppose I could do a row by row and column by column comparison, but is there an easier way?

Comment: From pandas 1.1 you can easily do this with a [single function call - `df.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html).

Comment: Note: for compare to work the dataframes need to be IDENTICALLY shaped. So if you're trying to find out if a row has been added or removed you're out of luck.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The first part is similar to Constantine, you can get the boolean of which rows are empty*:

```
In [21]: ne = (df1 != df2).any(1)

In [22]: ne
Out[22]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Then we can see which entries have changed:

```
In [23]: ne_stacked = (df1 != df2).stack()

In [24]: changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]

In [25]: changed.index.names = ['id', 'col']

In [26]: changed
Out[26]:
id  col
1   score         True
2   isEnrolled    True
    Comment       True
dtype: bool
```

*Here the first entry is the index and the second the columns which has been changed.*

```
In [27]: difference_locations = np.where(df1 != df2)

In [28]: changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]

In [29]: changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]

In [30]: pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to}, index=changed.index)
Out[30]:
               from           to
id col
1  score       1.11         1.21
2  isEnrolled  True        False
   Comment     None  On vacation
```

* Note: it's important that `df1` and `df2` share the same index here. To overcome this ambiguity, you can ensure you only look at the shared labels using `df1.index & df2.index`, but I think I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I believe "share the same index" means "make sure that index is sorted"...this will compare whatever is first in `df1` to whatever is first in `df2`, regardless of the value of the index.  JFYI in case I'm not the only person for which this wasn't obvious. ;D  Thanks!

Comment: If score is equal to `nan` in both df1 and df1, this function will report it as having changed from `nan` to `nan`. This is because `np.nan != np.nan` returns `True`.

Comment: @kungfujam is right.  Also, if the values being compared are None you will get false differences there too

Comment: Just to be clear - I illustrate the issue with this solution and provide an easy to use function which fixes the problem [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d/38421614#38421614)

Comment: ['row', 'col'] is preferable than ['id','col'] as changed.index.names, because it's not ids, but rows.

Answer (score 140):

### Highlighting the difference between two DataFrames

It is possible to use the DataFrame style property to highlight the background color of the cells where there is a difference.

**Using the example data from the original question**

The first step is to concatenate the DataFrames horizontally with the `concat` function and distinguish each frame with the `keys` parameter:

```
df_all = pd.concat([df.set_index('id'), df2.set_index('id')], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'])
df_all
```

[image]

It's probably easier to swap the column levels and put the same column names next to each other:

```
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df.columns[1:]]
df_final
```

[image]

Now, its much easier to spot the differences in the frames. But, we can go further and use the `style` property to highlight the cells that are different. We define a custom function to do this which you can see in [this part of the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Building-Styles).

```
def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
```

[image]

This will highlight cells that both have missing values. You can either fill them or provide extra logic so that they don't get highlighted.

Comment: Do you know how whether it is possible to color both 'First' and 'Second' in different colors?

Comment: Is it possible to select only different rows? In this case how do I select second and third row without selecting first row (111)?

Comment: @shantanuo, yes, just edit the final method to `df_final[(df != df2).any(1)].style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)`

Comment: This implementation is taking a longer time when comparing dataframes with 26K rows and 400 columns. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: @Ted Petrou your code is really, really beautiful, but it doesn't work on my files. I have 2 files with diffrenet number of raws

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work with dates. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: how do i drop row if all the values matches between first and second df during concat ? ex 111 row

Answer (score 60):

This answer simply extends @Andy Hayden's, making it resilient to when numeric fields are `nan`, and wrapping it up into a function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def diff_pd(df1, df2):
    """Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
    assert (df1.columns == df2.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if any(df1.dtypes != df2.dtypes):
        "Data Types are different, trying to convert"
        df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
    if df1.equals(df2):
        return None
    else:
        # need to account for np.nan != np.nan returning True
        diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['id', 'col']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
        changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]
        changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
        return pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)
```

So with your data (slightly edited to have a NaN in the score column):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

DF1 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.11                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     True                  " "
""")
DF2 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.21                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     False                "On vacation" """)
df1 = pd.read_table(DF1, sep='\s+', index_col='id')
df2 = pd.read_table(DF2, sep='\s+', index_col='id')
diff_pd(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
                from           to
id  col                          
112 score       1.11         1.21
113 isEnrolled  True        False
    Comment           On vacation
```

Comment: I added code to take care of minor differences in datatype, which would throw an error, if you didn't account for it.

Comment: What if I don't have identical rows on either side to compare?

Comment: @KishorkumarR then you should even out the rows first, by detecting added rows to the new dataframe, and removed rows from the old dataframe

Comment: Great answer.  I found it helpful to add the following, in case column order was misaligned due to previous transformations.  `df1 = df1.reindex(sorted(df1.columns), axis=1)
df2 = df2.reindex(sorted(df2.columns), axis=1)`

Comment: this function blows up when the index labels differ with `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects` - this function would be stronger or more powerful if it also accounted for that case.

Answer (score 28):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

texts = ['''\
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled                        Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 He was late to class
112  Nick   1.11                     False                           Graduated
113  Zoe    4.12                     True       ''',

         '''\
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled                        Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 He was late to class
112  Nick   1.21                     False                           Graduated
113  Zoe    4.12                     False                         On vacation''']


df1 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(texts[0]), widths=[5,7,25,21,20])
df2 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(texts[1]), widths=[5,7,25,21,20])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]) 

print(df)
#     id  Name  score isEnrolled               Comment
# 0  111  Jack   2.17       True  He was late to class
# 1  112  Nick   1.11      False             Graduated
# 2  113   Zoe   4.12       True                   NaN
# 0  111  Jack   2.17       True  He was late to class
# 1  112  Nick   1.21      False             Graduated
# 2  113   Zoe   4.12      False           On vacation

df.set_index(['id', 'Name'], inplace=True)
print(df)
#           score isEnrolled               Comment
# id  Name                                        
# 111 Jack   2.17       True  He was late to class
# 112 Nick   1.11      False             Graduated
# 113 Zoe    4.12       True                   NaN
# 111 Jack   2.17       True  He was late to class
# 112 Nick   1.21      False             Graduated
# 113 Zoe    4.12      False           On vacation

def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} | {}'.format(*x)

changes = df.groupby(level=['id', 'Name']).agg(report_diff)
print(changes)
```

prints

```
                score    isEnrolled               Comment
id  Name                                                 
111 Jack         2.17          True  He was late to class
112 Nick  1.11 | 1.21         False             Graduated
113 Zoe          4.12  True | False     nan | On vacation
```

Comment: Very nice solution, much more compact that mine!

Comment: @AndyHayden: I'm not entirely comfortable with this solution; it seems to work only when the index is a multilevel index. If I try using only `id` as the index, then `df.groupby(level='id')` raises an error, and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 23):

## pandas >= 1.1: [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

With pandas 1.1, you could essentially replicate Ted Petrou's output with a single function call. Example taken from the docs:

```
pd.__version__
# '1.1.0'

df1.compare(df2)

  score       isEnrolled       Comment             
   self other       self other    self        other
1  1.11  1.21        NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN
2   NaN   NaN        1.0   0.0     NaN  On vacation
```

Here, "self" refers to the LHS dataFrame, while "other" is the RHS DataFrame. By default, equal values are replaced with NaNs so you can focus on just the diffs. If you want to show values that are equal as well, use

```
df1.compare(df2, keep_equal=True, keep_shape=True) 

  score       isEnrolled           Comment             
   self other       self  other       self        other
1  1.11  1.21      False  False  Graduated    Graduated
2  4.12  4.12       True  False        NaN  On vacation
```

You can also change the axis of comparison using `align_axis`:

```
df1.compare(df2, align_axis='index')

         score  isEnrolled      Comment
1 self    1.11         NaN          NaN
  other   1.21         NaN          NaN
2 self     NaN         1.0          NaN
  other    NaN         0.0  On vacation
```

This compares values row-wise, instead of column-wise.

Comment: i have similar situation, but, problem is that my df_all comes from concatenating 2 or more df(df1, df2) and i am required to track changes in df_all and identify which of the dfs(df1 or df2) got changed. can you point out if this question already answered, I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 22):

I have faced this issue, but found an answer before finding this post :

Based on unutbu's answer, load your data...

```
import pandas as pd
import io

texts = ['''\
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled                       Date
111  Jack                            True              2013-05-01 12:00:00
112  Nick   1.11                     False             2013-05-12 15:05:23
     Zoe    4.12                     True                                  ''',

         '''\
id   Name   score                    isEnrolled                       Date
111  Jack   2.17                     True              2013-05-01 12:00:00
112  Nick   1.21                     False                                
     Zoe    4.12                     False             2013-05-01 12:00:00''']


df1 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(texts[0]), widths=[5,7,25,17,20], parse_dates=[4])
df2 = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(texts[1]), widths=[5,7,25,17,20], parse_dates=[4])
```

...define your *diff* function...

```
def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} | {}'.format(*x)
```

Then you can simply use a Panel to conclude :

```
my_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))
print my_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)

#          id  Name        score    isEnrolled                       Date
#0        111  Jack   nan | 2.17          True        2013-05-01 12:00:00
#1        112  Nick  1.11 | 1.21         False  2013-05-12 15:05:23 | NaT
#2  nan | nan   Zoe         4.12  True | False  NaT | 2013-05-01 12:00:00
```

By the way, if you're in IPython Notebook, you may like to use a colored *diff* function
to give colors depending whether cells are different, equal or left/right null :

```
from IPython.display import HTML
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 500  # You need this, otherwise pandas
#                          will limit your HTML strings to 50 characters

def report_diff(x):
    if x[0]==x[1]:
        return unicode(x[0].__str__())
    elif pd.isnull(x[0]) and pd.isnull(x[1]):
        return u'<table style="background-color:#00ff00;font-weight:bold;">'+\
            '<tr><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>' % ('nan', 'nan')
    elif pd.isnull(x[0]) and ~pd.isnull(x[1]):
        return u'<table style="background-color:#ffff00;font-weight:bold;">'+\
            '<tr><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>' % ('nan', x[1])
    elif ~pd.isnull(x[0]) and pd.isnull(x[1]):
        return u'<table style="background-color:#0000ff;font-weight:bold;">'+\
            '<tr><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>' % (x[0],'nan')
    else:
        return u'<table style="background-color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;">'+\
            '<tr><td>%s</td></tr><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>' % (x[0], x[1])

HTML(my_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0).to_html(escape=False))
```

Comment: (In regular Python, not iPython notebook) is it possible in include `my_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))` inside the function `report_diff()`? I mean, is it possible to do this: `print report_diff(df1,df2)` and get the same output as your print statement?

Comment: `pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2)).apply(report_diff, axis=0)` -  this is awesome!!!

Comment: Panels are deprecated! Any idea how to port this?

Comment: @denfromufa I took a swing at updating it in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038417/7607701

Answer (score 12):

A different approach using concat and drop_duplicates:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

DF1 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.11                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     True                  " "
""")
DF2 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.21                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     False                "On vacation" """)

df1 = pd.read_table(DF1, sep='\s+', index_col='id')
df2 = pd.read_table(DF2, sep='\s+', index_col='id')
#%%
dictionary = {1:df1,2:df2}
df=pd.concat(dictionary)
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Output:

```
       Name  score isEnrolled      Comment
  id                                      
1 112  Nick   1.11      False    Graduated
  113   Zoe    NaN       True             
2 112  Nick   1.21      False    Graduated
  113   Zoe    NaN      False  On vacation
```

Answer (score 11):

If your two dataframes have the same ids in them, then finding out what changed is actually pretty easy. Just doing `frame1 != frame2` will give you a boolean DataFrame where each `True` is data that has changed. From that, you could easily get the index of each changed row by doing `changedids = frame1.index[np.any(frame1 != frame2,axis=1)]`.

Answer (score 6):

After fiddling around with @journois's answer, I was able to get it to work using MultiIndex instead of Panel due to [Panel's deprication](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-panel).

First, create some dummy data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555'],
    'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'num': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['111', '222', '333', '444', '666'],
    'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'f'],
    'num': ['1', '2', 'Three', '4', '6'],
})
```

Then, define your *diff* function, in this case I'll use the one from his answer `report_diff` stays the same:

```
def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} | {}'.format(*x)
```

Then, I'm going to concatenate the data into a MultiIndex dataframe:

```
df_all = pd.concat(
    [df1.set_index('id'), df2.set_index('id')], 
    axis='columns', 
    keys=['df1', 'df2'],
    join='outer'
)
df_all = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]
```

And finally I'm going to apply the `report_diff` down each column group:

```
df_final.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda frame: frame.apply(report_diff, axis=1))
```

This outputs:

```
         let        num
111        a          1
222        b          2
333        c  3 | Three
444    d | D          4
555  e | nan    5 | nan
666  nan | f    nan | 6
```

And that is all!

Comment: Please replace df_final with df_all.

Answer (score 4):

Extending answer of @cge, which is pretty cool for more readability of result:

```
a[a != b][np.any(a != b, axis=1)].join(pd.DataFrame('a<->b', index=a.index, columns=['a<=>b'])).join(
        b[a != b][np.any(a != b, axis=1)]
        ,rsuffix='_b', how='outer'
).fillna('')
```

Full demonstration example:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7,3), columns=list('ABC'))
b = a.copy()
b.iloc[0,2] = np.nan
b.iloc[1,0] = 7
b.iloc[3,1] = 77
b.iloc[4,2] = 777

a[a != b][np.any(a != b, axis=1)].join(pd.DataFrame('a<->b', index=a.index, columns=['a<=>b'])).join(
        b[a != b][np.any(a != b, axis=1)]
        ,rsuffix='_b', how='outer'
).fillna('')
```

Sample result: [image]

[Online demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/195jzQ4KotvjlKpcSAQVUKCU8Z1pxh-zm?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using select and merge:

```
In [6]: # first lets create some dummy dataframes with some column(s) different
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(-5,0), 'b': range(10,15), 'c': range(20,25)})
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(-5,0), 'b': range(10,15), 'c': [20] + list(range(101,105))})


In [7]: df1
Out[7]:
   a   b   c
0 -5  10  20
1 -4  11  21
2 -3  12  22
3 -2  13  23
4 -1  14  24


In [8]: df2
Out[8]:
   a   b    c
0 -5  10   20
1 -4  11  101
2 -3  12  102
3 -2  13  103
4 -1  14  104


In [10]: # make condition over the columns you want to comapre
    ...: condition = df1['c'] != df2['c']
    ...:
    ...: # select rows from each dataframe where the condition holds
    ...: diff1 = df1[condition]
    ...: diff2 = df2[condition]


In [11]: # merge the selected rows (dataframes) with some suffixes (optional)
    ...: diff1.merge(diff2, on=['a','b'], suffixes=('_before', '_after'))
Out[11]:
   a   b  c_before  c_after
0 -4  11        21      101
1 -3  12        22      102
2 -2  13        23      103
3 -1  14        24      104
```

Here is the same thing from a Jupyter screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you found this thread trying to compare data fames in tests, then take a look at `assert_frame_equal` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

Answer (score 0):

A function that finds asymmetrical  difference between two data frames is implemented below:
(Based on [set difference for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas/40209800#40209800))
GIST: https://gist.github.com/oneryalcin/68cf25f536a25e65f0b3c84f9c118e03

```
def diff_df(df1, df2, how="left"):
    """
      Find Difference of rows for given two dataframes
      this function is not symmetric, means
            diff(x, y) != diff(y, x)
      however
            diff(x, y, how='left') == diff(y, x, how='right')

      Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas/40209800#40209800
    """
    if (df1.columns != df2.columns).any():
        raise ValueError("Two dataframe columns must match")

    if df1.equals(df2):
        return None
    elif how == 'right':
        return pd.concat([df2, df1, df1]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    elif how == 'left':
        return pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    else:
        raise ValueError('how parameter supports only "left" or "right keywords"')
```

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
Out[1]: 
                Comment  Name  isEnrolled  score
0  He was late to class  Jack        True   2.17
1             Graduated  Nick       False   1.11
2                         Zoe        True   4.12


df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

Out[2]: 
                Comment  Name  isEnrolled  score
0  He was late to class  Jack        True   2.17
1           On vacation   Zoe        True   4.12

diff_df(df1, df2)
Out[3]: 
     Comment  Name  isEnrolled  score
1  Graduated  Nick       False   1.11
2              Zoe        True   4.12

diff_df(df2, df1)
Out[4]: 
       Comment Name  isEnrolled  score
1  On vacation  Zoe        True   4.12

# This gives the same result as above
diff_df(df1, df2, how='right')
Out[22]: 
       Comment Name  isEnrolled  score
1  On vacation  Zoe        True   4.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Dataframe.compare to do this now since v1.1.0

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer is on how to get a simple dataframe, that is the difference of two other ones, which is something similar to ops question, but not exactly the same.

## approaches

There are 2 options you have in detail:

1. You get a dataframe with all rows from the first dataframe, that are not contained in the second dataframe.
2. You get a dataframe with all rows from the second dataframe, that are not contained in the first dataframe
3. You get a dataframe with all rows from option 1 and option 2

## code

```py
# option 1
def diff_pd(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame)  -> pd.DataFrame:
    common_rows = df1[df1.isin(df2.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]

    return = df1[~df1.isin(common_rows.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
```

```py
# option 2
def diff_pd(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame)  -> pd.DataFrame:
    common_rows = df1[df1.isin(df2.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]

    return = df2[~df2.isin(common_rows.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
```

For the third and most complex option, you just concat the results from option 1 and 2.

```py
# option 3
def diff_pd(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    common_rows = df1[df1.isin(df2.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]

    df1 = df1[~df1.isin(common_rows.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
    df2 = df2[~df2.isin(common_rows.to_dict(orient='list')).all(axis=1)]

    return pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('D:\\HARISH\\DATA SCIENCE\\1 MY Training\\SAMPLE DATA & projs\\CRICKET DATA\\IPL PLAYER LIST\\IPL PLAYER LIST _ harish.xlsx')


df1= srh = df[df['TEAM'].str.contains("SRH")]
df2 = csk = df[df['TEAM'].str.contains("CSK")]   

srh = srh.iloc[:,0:2]
csk = csk.iloc[:,0:2]

csk = csk.reset_index(drop=True)
csk

srh = srh.reset_index(drop=True)
srh

new = pd.concat([srh, csk], axis=1)

new.head()
```

> ```
> ** 
>                PLAYER     TYPE           PLAYER         TYPE
>
> 0        David Warner  Batsman    ...        MS Dhoni      Captain
>
> 1  Bhuvaneshwar Kumar   Bowler  ...    Ravindra Jadeja  All-Rounder
>
> 2       Manish Pandey  Batsman   ...   Suresh Raina  All-Rounder
>
> 3   Rashid Khan Arman   Bowler     ...   Kedar Jadhav  All-Rounder
>
> 4      Shikhar Dhawan  Batsman    ....    Dwayne Bravo  All-Rounder
> ```

Comment: Hello Harish, please format your answer a bit more, otherwise its quite hard to read :)