# set difference for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A simple pandas question:

Is there a `drop_duplicates()` functionality to drop every row involved in the duplication?

An equivalent question is the following: Does pandas have a set difference for dataframes?

For example:

```
In [5]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})

In [6]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,2,5], 'col2':[6,3,5]})

In [7]: df1
Out[7]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4

In [8]: df2
Out[8]: 
   col1  col2
0     4     6
1     2     3
2     5     5
```

so maybe something like `df2.set_diff(df1)` will produce this:

```
   col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

However, I don't want to rely on indexes because in my case, I have to deal with dataframes that have distinct indexes.

By the way, I initially thought about an extension of the current `drop_duplicates()` method, but now I realize that the second approach using properties of set theory would be far more useful in general. Both approaches solve my current problem, though.

Thanks!

Comment: yes there is drop_duplicates method... CHeck documentation http://pandas.pydata.org.   Depending on how data is structured you should be able to do set operations too.   can definately replace items in frame with items from another frame.   Not sure offhand if it is possible to check for uniqueness across all the columns

Comment: Can you point out how to perform set operations?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and tell us what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: Sure. I will update in a few minutes.

Comment: if there are non duplicates... which dataframe has the accurate ones.   Ie do you merely want to find the unique items or do you need to merge them with some additional logic?

Comment: @Joop If there are no duplicates, set difference returns the first dataframe (e.g. df2.set_diff(df1) returns df2)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
from pandas import  DataFrame

df1 = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'col1':[4,2,5], 'col2':[6,3,5]})


print(df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(1)])
print(df2[(df2!=df1)].dropna(how='all'))
print(df2[~(df2==df1)].dropna(how='all'))
```

Comment: I believe this solution only works if this indexes are identical on both DataFrames. @Joop has an answer that works without this condition.

Comment: I wish this answer was explained a little more for those of us trying to follow along.  I think that all three answers are the same, but they give different data types in the results.  I think the ~ negates the operation, but what is the purpose of .all(1)?

Comment: @David, .all(axis) - axis : {0, 1}. 0 for row-wise, 1 for column-wise.So to check if all columns (axis=1) are null.. .all(1) is used. check result without .all(1)

Comment: The first does not work if you have Nones in your data. Example:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,None,4]})`
`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,None,4]})`

`print(df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(1)])`

Answer (score 73):

Bit convoluted but if you want to totally ignore the index data.    Convert the contents of the dataframes to sets of tuples containing the columns:

```
ds1 = set(map(tuple, df1.values))
ds2 = set(map(tuple, df2.values))
```

This step will get rid of any duplicates in the dataframes as well (index ignored)

```
set([(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3)])   # ds1
```

can then use set methods to find anything.  Eg to find differences:

```
ds1.difference(ds2)
```

gives:
set([(1, 2), (3, 4)])

can take that back to dataframe if needed.  Note have to transform set to list 1st as set cannot be used to construct dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(ds1.difference(ds2)))
```

Comment: Fantastic. This worked perfectly. Obviously, it reorders the rows but that's not a problem. Maybe the only problem associated with this is that df1 needs to be converted to a set first, so that will remove duplicates in df1 which might not be desired. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes set per definition creates an unordered data structure.  Not sure if there is a pure pandas alternative, but seeing that the index data is not important to you it makes sense to use the built in methods.  Be sure to check out @Jeff solution.  He is a real pandas expert and might be quicker than my code.  Also staying in pandas data structure will preserve the index data, which might still be of use to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found a small bug. If you're dealing with numbers that require a reasonable precision, this will cause some issues because it rounds to the nearest decimal. In my case, it's the 7th decimal that gets rounded.

Comment: What is the computational complexity of this? This seems unacceptably slow, no?

Comment: This is extremely slow. Something that uses compiled C (ie numpy or pandas) would be way better

Answer (score 60):

Here's another answer that keeps the index and does not require identical indexes in two data frames. (EDIT: make sure there is no duplicates in df2 beforehand)

```
pd.concat([df2, df1, df1]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

It is fast and the result is

```
   col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

Comment: That's clever. Of course, it doesn't have the flexibility of a set theoretic function.

Comment: FYI link is broken

Comment: That answer implies that there is any duplicated rows in df2 (df2 is already at set of rows)

Comment: @guilloptero: you could modify by dropping any duplicates in df2 before running

Comment: @BryanP's suggestion works:
 `pd.concat([df2.drop_duplicates(), df1, df1]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

Answer (score 6):

Numpy's setdiff1d would work and perhaps be faster.

For each column:
`np.setdiff1(df1.col1.values, df2.col1.values)`

So something like:

```
setdf = pd.DataFrame({
    col: np.setdiff1d(getattr(df1, col).values, getattr(df2, col).values)
    for col in df1.columns
})
```

[numpy.setdiff1d docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 methods which work, but two of them have some flaws.

**Method 1 (Hash method):**

It worked for all cases I tested.

```
df1.loc[:, "hash"] = df1.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)
df2.loc[:, "hash"] = df2.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)
df1 = df1.loc[~df1["hash"].isin(df2["hash"]), :]
```

**Method 2 (Dict method):**

It fails if DataFrames contain datetime columns.

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.isin(df2.to_dict(orient="list")).all(axis=1), :]
```

**Method 3 (MultiIndex method):**

I encountered cases when it failed on columns with None's or NaN's.

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1.set_index(list(df1.columns)).index.isin(df2.set_index(list(df2.columns)).index)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: You can now make MultiIndex objects directly from data frames as of pandas 0.24.0 which greatly simplifies the syntax of this answer**

```
df1mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
df2mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)
dfdiff = df2mi.difference(df1mi).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**Original Answer**

Pandas MultiIndex objects have fast set operations implemented as methods, so you can convert the DataFrames to MultiIndexes, use the `difference()` method, then convert the result back to a DataFrame. This solution should be much faster (by ~100x or more from my brief testing) than the solutions given here so far, and it will not depend on the row indexing of the original frames. As Piotr mentioned for his answer, this will fail with null values, since np.nan != np.nan. Any row in df2 with a null value will always appear in the difference. Also, the columns should be in the same order for both DataFrames.

```
df1mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values.transpose(), names=df1.columns)
df2mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.values.transpose(), names=df2.columns)
dfdiff = df2mi.difference(df1mi).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Apply by the columns of the object you want to map (df2); find the rows that are not in the set (`isin` is like a set operator)

```
In [32]: df2.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[~x.isin(df1[x.name]),x.name])
Out[32]: 
   col1  col2
0     4     6
2     5     5
```

Same thing, but include all values in df1, but still per column in df2

```
In [33]: df2.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[~x.isin(df1.values.ravel()),x.name])
Out[33]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN     6
2     5     5
```

2nd example

```
In [34]: g = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1.2,1.5,1.3], 'y': [4,4,4]})

In [35]: g.columns=df1.columns

In [36]: g
Out[36]: 
   col1  col2
0   1.2     4
1   1.5     4
2   1.3     4

In [32]: g.apply(lambda x: g.loc[~x.isin(df1[x.name]),x.name])
Out[32]: 
   col1  col2
0   1.2   NaN
1   1.5   NaN
2   1.3   NaN
```

Note, in 0.13, there will be an `isin` operator on the frame level, so something like: `df2.isin(df1)` should be possible

Comment: Interesting. For some reason, I couldn't make it work. It returned a lot of NaN's, so I need to see what went wrong.

Comment: I think there is a problem. If you have something like this: `g = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1.2,1.5,1.3], 'y': [4,4,4]})` and you want to remove `g.ix[[0,2]]`, then this won't select the correct rows because it checks if every element of g is in g.ix[[0,2]]. The second row includes a number (4) that is equal to one of g.ix[[0,2]] (actually, two of them are equal).

Comment: I am not clear on your comment; what would you expected as the result of ``g.set_diff(df1)`` (or the reverse)

Comment: g.set_diff(df1) should return the rows in g that are not included in df1.

Answer (score 3):

Get the indices of the intersection with a merge, then drop them:

```
>>> df_all = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((4,2)), columns=['A','B']); df_all
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
>>> df_completed = df_all.iloc[::2]; df_completed
   A  B
0  0  1
2  4  5
>>> merged = pd.merge(df_all.reset_index(), df_completed); merged
   index  A  B
0      0  0  1
1      2  4  5
>>> df_pending = df_all.drop(merged['index']); df_pending
   A  B
1  2  3
3  6  7
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:

> 1. df1 and df2 have identical columns
> 2. it is a set operation so duplicates are ignored
> 3. sets are not extremely large so you do not worry about memory

```
union = pd.concat([df1,df2])
sym_diff = union[~union.duplicated(keep=False)]
union_of_df1_and_sym_diff = pd.concat([df1, sym_diff])
diff = union_of_df1_and_sym_diff[union_of_df1_and_sym_diff.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `pd.concat()` implicitly joins overlapping columns but I had to do a little tweak on @radream's answer.

Conceptually, a set difference ([symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)) on multiple columns is a set union (outer join) minus a set intersection (or inner join):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,2,5], 'col2':[6,3,5]})
o = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
i = pd.merge(df1, df2)
set_diff = pd.concat([o, i]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

This yields:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     2
2     3     4
3     4     6
4     5     5
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas 1.1.0 you can count unique rows with `value_counts` and find difference between counts:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,2,5], 'col2':[6,3,5]})

diff = df2.value_counts().sub(df1.value_counts(), fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
col1  col2
1     2      -1.0
2     3       0.0
3     4      -1.0
4     6       1.0
5     5       1.0
dtype: float64
```

Get positive counts:

```
diff[diff > 0].reset_index(name='counts')


   col1  col2  counts
0     4     6     1.0
1     5     5     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of is to use `pd.merge` with `how='outer'` and `indicator=True`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',left_on=['col1'],right_on=['col1'],indicator=True)
```

The resulting table will contain an new column `_merge` with the values `right_only`, `left_only` and `both` that you can then filter out. I.E.

```
df3[df3['_merge']=='left_only']
```

The upside to this approach is flexibility in that you can use ordered lists of columns for your definition of equality across the two tables. I.E. `left_on=['col1','col2'],right_on=['col1','col3']`.

Or if you meant something different by set difference you can use `df3[~(df3['_merge']=='both')]` or `df3[~(df3['_merge']=='right_only')]` or what ever matches your needs.

The downside is that you are doing a full outer join on the two tables and you may end up with a messy table requiring extra cleanup.

Answer (score -1):

this should work even if you have multiple columns in both dataframes. But make sure that the column names of both the dataframes are the exact same.

```
set_difference = pd.concat([df2, df1, df1]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

With multiple columns you can also use:

```
col_names=['col_1','col_2']
set_difference = pd.concat([df2[col_names], df1[col_names], 
df1[col_names]]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```