# How to remove a pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

How to remove a pandas dataframe from another dataframe, just like the set subtraction:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,5]
a-b=[2,3,4]
```

And now we have two pandas dataframe, how to remove df2 from df1:

```
In [5]: df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['a','b'])
In [6]: df1
Out[6]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6


In [9]: df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,6]],columns=['a','b'])
In [10]: df2
Out[10]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  5  6
```

Then we expect df1-df2 result will be:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   a  b
0  3  4
```

How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set difference for pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas)

Comment: @176coding Please timeit our answers on your real datasets - it's interesting to me which is fastest/

Answer (score 115):

## Solution

Use `pd.concat` followed by `drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

It looks like

```
   a  b
1  3  4
```

## Explanation

`pd.concat` adds the two `DataFrame`s together by appending one right after the other.  if there is any overlap, it will be captured by the `drop_duplicates` method.  However, `drop_duplicates` by default leaves the first observation and removes every other observation.  In this case, we want every duplicate removed.  Hence, the `keep=False` parameter which does exactly that.

A special note to the repeated `df2`.  With only one `df2` any row in `df2` not in `df1` won't be considered a duplicate and will remain.  This solution with only one `df2` only works when `df2` is a subset of `df1`.  However, if we concat `df2` twice, it is guaranteed to be a duplicate and will subsequently be removed.

Comment: thx, it works, and we can use `pd.concat(df1,df2).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` or `df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

Comment: @176coding hopefully this answers your question.  If not, let me know what remains unanswered and i'll do my best to address it.

Comment: @piRSquared Your answer isn't correct - you made symmetric difference, not difference (simple).

Comment: THis does not work.  It the df you concatenate has additional records that are NOT in the checked df, then they will be Added to it...

Comment: The primary dataframe is `df1`.  I'm concatenating 3 dataframes, `df1` once and `df2` twice.  Because `df2` is concatenated twice, by definition, everything in it will be duplicated.  Therefore, dropping duplicates will leave NOTHING that was in `df2`.

Comment: Further, the only issue that this does not address is if there are existing duplicates in the initial dataframe.  This assumes there are no duplicates in the initial dataframe.

Comment: Your answer is super clear. However, it returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error when I try to drop duplicates. Can you check it? And if it is the case, can you update your answer?

Comment: @justRandomLearner that implies that the items you are trying to check for duplication are are lists.  If I'm correct, you need to change those items to a hashable type.  If all items are lists, you may want to make them all tuples instead.  If this doesn't make sense, feel free to ask a new question following the advice here -> [mcve].  If you add a reply to this comment with a link to that question, I'll try to check it out and make sure you get your answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `.duplicated`, which has the benefit of being fairly expressive:

```
%%timeit
combined = df1.append(df2)
combined[~combined.index.duplicated(keep=False)]

1000 loops, best of 3: 875 µs per loop
```

For comparison:

```
%timeit df1.loc[pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b'], how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'left_only']

100 loops, best of 3: 4.57 ms per loop


%timeit pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

1000 loops, best of 3: 987 µs per loop


%timeit df2[df2.apply(lambda x: x.value not in df2.values, axis=1)]

1000 loops, best of 3: 546 µs per loop
```

In sum, using the `np.array` comparison is fastest. Don't need the `.tolist()` there.

Comment: Be careful: This only works if the substracted Dataframe only contains data that is included in the first one. But I do like this answer.

Comment: Which of these would also work on Series?

Answer (score 15):

To get dataframe with all records which are in DF1 but not in DF2

```
DF=DF1[~DF1.isin(DF2)].dropna(how = 'all')
```

Comment: Such an elegant and pythonic solution. Works for me. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call pandas syntax pythonic at all, but this seems by far the best solution, not having to destroy your original dataframe duplicates to drop the contents of another dataframe. Got my upvote sir

Answer (score 6):

A set logic approach.  Turn the rows of `df1` and `df2` into sets.  Then use `set` subtraction to define new `DataFrame`

```
idx1 = set(df1.set_index(['a', 'b']).index)
idx2 = set(df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index)

pd.DataFrame(list(idx1 - idx2), columns=df1.columns)

   a  b
0  3  4
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution works when your *df_to_drop* is a subset of main data frame *data*.

`data_clean = data.drop(df_to_drop.index)`

Answer (score 2):

A masking approach

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist() not in df2.values.tolist(), axis=1)]

   a  b
1  3  4
```

Comment: don't need `.tolist()`.

Answer (score 2):

My shot with merge df1 and df2 from the question.

Using 'indicator' parameter

```
In [74]: df1.loc[pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b'], how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'left_only']
Out[74]: 
   a  b
1  3  4
```

Comment: An explanation of what is happening would make this a richer answer. You mentioned that the key to this method's success is the 'indicator' parameter, and setting that to true will add location information to each row, which your solution uses in the final step to filter, keeping only rows that appear only in the left data frame (indicator == 'left_only').

Answer (score 0):

I think the first `tolist()` needs to be removed, but keep the second one:

```
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.values() not in df2.values.tolist(), axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easiest option is to use indexes.

1. Append df1 and df2 and reset their indexes.

   `df = df1.concat(df2)`
   `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`
2. e.g:
   This will give df2 indexes

   `indexes_df2 = df.index[ (df["a"].isin(df2["a"])  )  & (df["b"].isin(df2["b"])  )
   result_index = df.index[~index_df2]
   result_data = df.iloc[ result_index,:]`

Hope it will help to new readers, although the question posted a little time ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution if `df1` contains duplicates + keeps the index.

A modified version of [piRSquared's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313953/14700891) answer to keep the duplicates in `df1` that do not appear in `df2`, while maintaining the index.

```py
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: (x == pd.concat([df1.drop_duplicates(), df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)).all(1).any(), axis=1)]
```

If your dataframes are big, you may want to store the result of

```py
pd.concat([df1.drop_duplicates(), df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

in a variable before the `df1.apply` call.