# pandas - drop_duplicates not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

Following an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313953/1330355), I am trying to remove rows from one dataframe which are present in other dataframe.

It works well for this input:

csv1:

```
sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,141000,38.423251,-121.444489
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,146250,38.48742
```

csv2:

```
sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,146250,38.48742
```

Code:

```
>>> a = pd.read_csv('../test.csv', escapechar='\\')
>>> a
                      sale_date   price   latitude   longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000  38.423251 -121.444489
1  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250  38.487420         NaN

>>> b = pd.read_csv('../test1.csv', escapechar='\\')
>>> b
                      sale_date   price  latitude  longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250  38.48742        NaN

>>> pd.concat([a,b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                      sale_date   price   latitude   longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000  38.423251 -121.444489
```

This is working as expected. But as soon as there are other more rows in first csv, it doesnt work.

---

**Scenario 2 with extra row in csv1**

csv1:

```
sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,141000,38.423251,-121.444489
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,146250,38.48742
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,147308,38.658246a,-121.375469a
```

csv2:

```
sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,146250,38.48742
```

Code:

```
>>> a = pd.read_csv('../test.csv', escapechar='\\')
>>> a
                      sale_date   price    latitude     longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000   38.423251   -121.444489
1  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250    38.48742           NaN
2  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  147308  38.658246a  -121.375469a

>>> b = pd.read_csv('../test1.csv', escapechar='\\')
>>> b
                      sale_date   price  latitude  longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250  38.48742        NaN

>>> pd.concat([a,b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                      sale_date   price    latitude     longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000   38.423251   -121.444489
1  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250    38.48742           NaN
2  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  147308  38.658246a  -121.375469a
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  146250     38.4874           NaN
```

Notice that it also changed the latitude value for second duplicated in the merged row to `38.4874` from `38.48742`

Am I missing something here or pandas has a bug?

Comment: I cannot run python now, but it is interesting that in the `concat` the `latitude` of `b`  is truncated to `38.4874`. Therefore, it doesn't match the `38.48742` of the earlier row

Comment: @Jondiedoop yes even I noticed that and cross checked the value in csv. It is indeed truncating

Comment: np.NaN == np.NaN is False, so probably you can replace the NaN values with some constant and then do the drop_duplicate may work...

Comment: I wonder whether the non-numeric value of index 2 could have anything to do with it. Could you add the `dtypes` of the `latitude` column in all cases?

Comment: Nice catch @Jondiedoop. That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ayhan commented there is problem in `a` DataFrame are strings between numeric in columns `latitude` and `longitude`, so all columns are casted to strings.

In another DataFrame are columns by default casted to `float`s.

One possible solution is use `dtype` parameter for `b` DataFrame:

```
b = pd.read_csv('../test1.csv', escapechar='\\', dtype={'latitude':str, 'longitude':str})

df = pd.concat([a,b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print (df)
                      sale_date   price    latitude     longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000   38.423251   -121.444489
2  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  147308  38.658246a  -121.375469a
```

Or use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for columns in `a`:

```
a['latitude'] = pd.to_numeric(a['latitude'], errors='ignore')
a['longitude'] = pd.to_numeric(a['longitude'], errors='ignore')
df = pd.concat([a,b]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print (df)
                      sale_date   price    latitude     longitude
0  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  141000   38.423251   -121.444489
2  Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008  147308  38.658246a  -121.375469a
```

Comment: Thnaks. is there a way for me to make every column's dtype as str? I really dont care about dtypes

Comment: @MohitC - then use `a = pd.read_csv('../test.csv', escapechar='\\', dtype={'latitude':str, 'longitude':str})`

Comment: thats what i am asking, is there a way to specify dtype as str for all columns as a single parameter?

Comment: @MohitC - sure, use `a = pd.read_csv('../test.csv', escapechar='\\', dtype=str)`