# Computing Set Difference in Pandas between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Wondering how to compute set difference in Python's Pandas using two different dataframes.

One dataframe (df1) is of the format:

```
State  City          Population
NY     Albany        856654
WV     Wheeling      23434
SC     Charleston    35323
OH     Columbus      343534
WV     Charleston    34523
```

And the second data frame (df2) is

```
State  City
WV     Wheeling
OH     Columns
```

And I need an operation that returns the following data frame

```
State   City        Population
NY      Albany      856654
SC      Charleston  35323
WV      Charleston  34523
```

Essentially, I can't figure out how to "subtract" df2 from df1 based on the 2 columns (need both since I'll have repeats of city names across different states).

Comment: What are you filtering on here? State? State and city?

Comment: Are you looking for the set difference? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas

Comment: Had trouble making this solution work on my data, since I was dealing with two columns and my data frames didn't have the same structure!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do a left join with `indicator` which gives information on the origin of each row, then you can filter based on the `indicator`:

```
df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how="left")[lambda x: x._merge=='left_only'].drop('_merge',1)

#State       City   Population
#0  NY      Albany      856654
#2  SC  Charleston       35323
#4  WV  Charleston       34523
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked like a charm, although as a relative Pandas newbie, it seems pretty complicated for seems like a standard operation, something done easily in sql (or even brute force).  I'll take this, but 'm surprised there isn't a more elegant solution

Comment: Right. It might be helpful to have *anti-join* implemented in pandas, but it doesn't seem like so. And the work around surely is not elegant, but still acceptable which might be the reason why it's not implemented :).

Answer (score 2):

How about filters?

```
df1[~((df1.City.isin(df2.City)) & (df1.State.isin(df2.State)))]
```