# Subtraction of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference, subtraction

I am trying to substract two pandas dataframes from each other, but get only NaN results:

```
Dataframe 1:
   alpha  beta
0      1     4
1      2     5
2      3     6

Dataframe 2:
   gamma
0      7
1      8
2      9
```

Dataframe operation:

```
df3=df1-df2
```

Result:

```
alpha  beta  gamma
0    NaN   NaN    NaN
1    NaN   NaN    NaN
2    NaN   NaN    NaN
```

However, if I convert everything to numpy matrices, it works:

Matrix operation:

```
matrix3=df1.as_matrix(['alpha','beta'])-df2.as_matrix(['gamma'])
```

Result:

```
[[-6 -3]
[-6 -3]
[-6 -3]]
```

How can I make this work with pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set difference for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these work:

```
df['a'] = df['a'] - df2['gamma']
df['b'] = df['b'] - df2['gamma']
```

-

```
df.sub(df2.iloc[:,0],axis=0)
```

Comment: The first possibility works but was not my question. Especially it gets complicated if more columns are involved. The second one is exatly what I needed and answers the question. - Although I find it a bit cryptic.

Comment: For the first method, you could always multiply each column in a loop?