# How to group and calculate distance?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set as one below:

```
ID | X | Y | Z
--------------
 1 | 5 | 5 | 5
 1 | 4 | 2 | 0
 2 | 1 | 3 | 4
 .
 .
 .
```

I have ground truth values (x,y,z) for each ID. I want to calculate distance using the true values for each ID in the table above. I tried using `df.groupby()` but not sure how to stick the df back together.

True values:

```
ID | X | Y | Z
---------------
 1 | 1 | 2 | 3
 2 | 4 | 5 | 6
 3 | 7 | 8 | 9
 .
 .
```

I expect the output to look like:

```
ID | X  | Y  | Z
-----------------
 1 |  4 |  3 |  2
 1 |  3 |  0 | -3
 2 | -3 | -2 | -2
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: What is the expected output based on sample input?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `I have true (x,y,z) for each ID`? How do you calculate `True`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal if I understand correctly, he has a table of ground truths then a table of 'observations'. The ID column is used to identify which ground truth values to use.

Comment: Yes, @Riley got it right. Sorry for the ambiguity. I want to calculate euclidean distance basically. I have observations and they have IDs to true locations.

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227930/subtraction-of-pandas-dataframes.    df.sub(df2.iloc[:,0],axis=0)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `ID` as index and subtract. By doing so, `pandas` will align the correct `ID` (in this case, index) for you:

```
df.set_index('ID').sub(ground_truths.set_index('ID')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID    X    Y    Z
0   1  4.0  3.0  2.0
1   1  3.0  0.0 -3.0
2   2 -3.0 -2.0 -2.0
3   3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

**Update**: for Euclidean:

```
tmp = df.set_index('ID').sub(ground_truths.set_index('ID'))

# this is Euclidean part:
# you can use other packages, e.g. np.norm
result = ((tmp**2).sum(axis=1))**0.5
result = result.reset_index()
```

Comment: The true distance values are have unique IDs, say up to 30. But the values I have collected that have repeated IDs with different x,y,z are more than 30.

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi yes, this code should work. The fact that `ground_truths` having unique IDs is important.

Comment: i just tried it and it seems to work I believe. But as I mentioned, I am trying to find euclidean distance, so how would I pass these to a function or..

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.