# Find and remove rows in 1 data frame that do not exist in another using python pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 2 csv files of different length.  I need to find and remove the rows in one file that do not exist in the other file.
Is there an easy way to do this, other than looping through the 2nd file n times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set difference for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180763/set-difference-for-pandas)

Comment: Thank you, Andrey, that looks like a good resource.  I'm not looking for duplicate rows though.  So I wouldn't call this post a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you load your csv file into df1, and df2

```
df1[df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))]
```