# pandas - check changes in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d) question, and I've been working through it. I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` which look like:

**df1**:

```
U,T,L,P
01,string1,a,0.9
02,string2,b,0.9
03,string3,c,0.9
```

**df2**:

```
U,T,L,P
01,string1,a,0.9
02,string2,d,0.9
03,string3,c,0.9
```

Basically the only difference is in the `L` column and in the second row, where `b` becomes `d`. I would like to check this difference comparing the dataframes, keeping all the existing information. Following the above question, my attempts so far have been:

```
difference_locations = np.where(df1 != df2)

changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]

changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]

a = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to})
```

which returns:

```
  from to
0    b  d
```

The result is ok, but I would like to add also the remaining information about the initial datasets. The only changes occur in the columns `L` and `P`, and I would highlight the changes so that the result:

```
  U  T       from to
0 02 string2    b  d
```

I tried to build the dataframe adding the existing columns with something like:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'U': df1['U'],'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to})
```

but of course it doesn't work since I should perform a lookup over the index to get the right values of `U` and `T` in correspondence of the changed row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on column `L`. Then this column is renamed to `to`.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'L': changed_to})
print a
#   L from
#0  d    b

out = pd.merge(a, df2, on=['L'])
out.rename(columns={'L':'to'}, inplace=True)
out = out[['U','T','from', 'to']]
print out
#   U        T from to
#0  2  string2    b  d
```