# Python Pandas - Compare between two dataframes differences

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am creating a python application where I am trying to compare two Dataframes to identify differences. Given below is the piece of code where I am facing an issue. I am facing an issue in the below line, when it tries to compare between NaN and String/int

**different = (a0 != a1)**

**Error:**

TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array

**Code:**

```
df0 = Excel1.parse(sheet)
df1 = Excel2.parse(sheet)
a0, a1 = (df0.fillna('0')).align(df1.fillna('0'))
different = (a0 != a1)
comp = a0[different].join(a1[different], lsuffix='_old', rsuffix='_new')
```

Comment: See great answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d).

Answer (score 0):

May be convert the data frames into numpy arrays using `a0=df0.values` and `a1=df1.values`; then you will have two matrices `a0, a1`; to find cells which have different values, you may use `np.where(a0 != a1)`. Obviously, you may want to clean the data using `np.isnan()` or `np.isnf()` before doing the comparison.

It doesn't appear that any one array has only integers. If that is true, refer [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to ensure the two arrays are of the same type before doing the comparison.

`