# Show complete rows highliting difference between dataframes df1 , df2 , but only when difference in row's cell exists

Tags: python, pandas

i have two dataframes df1 and df2.
Same index and same column names.
how to construct a dataframe which shows difference, but only rows which have at least one different cell?
if row has different cells, but some are same, keep same cells intact.

example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({1:['a','a'],2:['c','c']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({1:['a','a'],2:['d','c']})
```

output needed:

```
pd.DataFrame({1:['a'],2:['c->d']},index=[0])
```

output in this example should be one row dataframe, not dataframe including same rows

NB: output should *only* contain *full* rows which has at least one difference in cell

i'd like an efficient solution without iterating by rows , and without creating special-strings in DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this brilliant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23088780/5741205):

```
def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{}->{}'.format(*x)

In [70]: pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2)).apply(report_diff, axis=0)
Out[70]:
   1     2
0  a  c->d
1  a     c
```

For bit more complex DataFrames:

```
In [73]: df1
Out[73]:
   A  B  C
0  a  c  1
1  a  c  2
2  1  2  3

In [74]: df2
Out[74]:
   A  B  C
0  a  d  1
1  a  c  2
2  1  2  4

In [75]: pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2)).apply(report_diff, axis=0)
Out[75]:
   A     B     C
0  a  c->d     1
1  a     c     2
2  1     2  3->4
```

**UPDATE:** showing only changed/different rows:

```
In [54]: mask = df1.ne(df2).any(1)

In [55]: mask
Out[55]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

In [56]: pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1[mask],df2=df2[mask])).apply(report_diff, axis=0)
Out[56]:
   A     B     C
0  a  c->d     1
2  1     2  3->4
```

Comment: I like it. Much more pandastic

Comment: yes i like report_diff solution  , but   i'd like my output dataframe without  same rows.  i edited the question to highlight it. dataframe can be 100MB and can contain any string or number

Comment: @alexprice, please see UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

How about a good ole list comprehension on the flattened contents...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame({1:['a','a'],2:['c','c']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({1:['a','a'],2:['d','c']})

rows_different_mask = (df1 != df2).any(axis=1)

pairs = zip(df1.values.reshape(1, -1)[0], df2.values.reshape(1, -1)[0])
new_elems = ["%s->%s" %(old, new) if (old != new) else new for old, new in pairs]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(new_elems, df1.values.shape))
print df3

   0     1
0  a  c->d
1  a     c
```