# comparing two DataFrames, specific questions

Tags: pandas

I was read Andy's answer to the question [Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)

i have two questions regarding the code, unfortunately I dont yet have 50 rep to comment on the answer so I hope i could get some help here.

1. what does `In [24]: changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]` do?
   I'm not sure what df1 = df[df] do and i cant seem to get an answer from pandas doc, could someone explain this to me please?
2. is `np.where(df1 != df2)` the same as `pd.df.where(df1 != df2)`. If no, what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

`ne_stacked` is a `pd.Series` that consists of `True` and `False` values that indicate where `df1` and `df2` are not equal.

`ne_stacked[boolean_array]` is a way to filter the series `ne_stacked` by eliminating the rows of `ne_stacked` where `boolean_array` is `False` and keeping the rows of `ne_stacked` where `boolean_array` is `True`.

It so happens that `ne_stacked` is also a boolean array and so can be used to filter itself.  Why would be want to do this?  So we can see what the values of the index are after we've filtered.

So `ne_stacked[ne_stacked]` is a subset of `ne_stacked` with only `True` values.

**Question 2**

**`np.where`**

`np.where` does two things, if you only pass a conditional like in `np.where(df1 != df2)`, you get a `tuple` of arrays where the first is a reference of all row indices to be used in conjunction with the second element of the `tuple` that is a reference to all column indices.  I usually use it like this

```
i, j = np.where(df1 != df2)
```

Now I can get at all elements of `df1` or `df2` in which there are differences like

```
df.values[i, j]
```

Or I can assign to those cells

```
df.values[i, j] = -99
```

Or lots of other useful things.

You can also use `np.where` as an if, then, else for arrays

```
np.where(df1 != df2, -99, 99)
```

To produce an array the same size as `df1` or `df2` where you have `-99` in all the places where `df1 != df2` and `99` in the rest.

**`df.where`**

On the other hand `df.where` evaluates the first argument of boolean values and returns an object of equal size to `df` where the cells that evaluated to `True` are kept and the rest are either `np.nan` or the values passed in the second argument of `df.where`

```
df1.where(df1 != df2)
```

Or

```
df1.where(df1 != df2, -99)
```

**are they the same?**
Clearly they are not the "same".  But you can use them similarly

```
np.where(df1 != df2, df1, -99)
```

Should be the same as

```
df1.where(df1 != df2, -99).values
```