# How to search same fiile and compare in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some directory and files

```
Directory1

file1
file2
file3

Directory2

file1
file2
file3
```

I would like to compare each file in each directory.

I tried

```
'glob.glob'
```

and

'read csv'

I guess I should have applied

'diff' 
method.

But I couldnt figure out next step.
How can I compare same name files in each directory?

Answer (score 1):

if you could read csv files and convert to data frames then this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by *compare*?

In order to get the list of files in your directory, you can use `os.listdir('directory_path')`, then you can iterate through the list and compare it with your reference file.
Also, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-dz) tells you how to compare the content of two dataframes in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a md5 checksum of the file content in a dict and search for equals checksums.

```
import glob
import hashlib

example = dict(('%s' % _, hashlib.md5(open('%s' % _, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()) for _ in glob.glob('*'))

{'file1': 'b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1', 'file2': '26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510', 'file3': '26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510', 'file4': '48a24b70a0b376535542b996af517398'}
```

Comment: file2 and file3 are equals.