# Highlighting the difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes containing dates:

df1:

```
Name  A             B             C  
D1    2018-04-26    2018-04-24    2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25    2018-04-23    2018-04-23
D3    2018-04-25    2018-04-26    2018-04-26
```

df2:

```
Name  A             B             C  
D1    2018-04-24    2018-04-23    2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25    2018-04-23    2018-04-21
D3    2018-04-22    2018-04-24    2018-04-23
```

Let's say i would like to style df1 such that if a value does not equal the corresponding value in df2, it highlights the cell red.

I know i need to create a function and use

```
df1.style.applymap()
```

but i'm having trouble putting the function together. Something like;

```
def diffindicator(val):
    color = 'white'   
    if val != df2:
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

Comment: `... i'm having trouble putting the function together...` - What does your function do, how is it deficient?

Comment: When I try to apply the function using 
df1styler= df1.style.applymap(diffindicator)
I get keyerrors on my indexes

Comment: Have you tried any other methods?

Comment: So I just tried
`def diffindicator(val):
    color = 'white'
    for c,r in df2.iterrows():
        if val != df2[c,r]:
            color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color`

But not im getting errors iterating over df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about highlighting the difference:

```
# Load Example Data
df1 = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
'''Name  A             B             C  
D1    2018-04-26    2018-04-24    2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25    2018-04-23    2018-04-23
D3    2018-04-25    2018-04-26    2018-04-26'''))
df2 = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
'''Name  A             B             C  
D1    2018-04-24    2018-04-23    2018-04-24
D2    2018-04-25    2018-04-23    2018-04-21
D3    2018-04-22    2018-04-24    2018-04-23'''))

def highlight_diff(data, other, color='pink'):
    # Define html attribute
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    # Where data != other set attribute
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

# Set axis=None so it passes the entire frame
df2.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None, other=df1)
```

Output:

[image: Difference between Frames]

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d) for a closer look on the subject of getting the difference between DataFrames...   In fact, my answer may or may not be inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112033/7607701).

Comment: I don't have the required dependencies here at work.  I came up with `def styl(df, other): st = df.where(df == other, 'background-color:red'); st = st.where(df != other, 'background-color:white');  return st` for the function, would you mind checking that?

Comment: @wwii is this in order to get the red/white background?

Comment: @wwii I edited my answer to make the color red.  (Or pink actually, nice red looked nasty)

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for a favor: if you could check my function to see if it works, I can't check it here at work.

Comment: @wwii Oh, I understand now, yes, it works: https://screenshots.firefox.com/HkmlTbV8tMpNl1j8/docker4.devops.iconectiv.com

Comment: Thanks @wwii, using your solution i was easily able to highlight df1 with different colors depending on if it was ahead of or behind df2