# How can I highlight in one color the cells that changed for a same row between two dataframes and in another color what is new? Different Shape

Tags: python, pandas, highlight

I tried many functions and tried to apply existing solutions to get the output I want, yet I seems not to be able to get an excel output at the end that keeps the formatting I try to apply.

It seems that all the function existing in pandas uses only identically labelled indexes, or files of the same shape, in my situation the shape of the two files are (757,26) for let's say file1 and (688,39) for file 2, the first 26 columns are labelled the same way for file1 and file2.

is there a way to merge these two files, highlight the differences as indicated in the title, and create an excel output with the formatting still present?

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas.io.formats.style as style

dfcurr=pd.read_excel(r'IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Current.xlsx')
dfprev=pd.read_excel(r'IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Previous.xlsx')

dfprev=dfprev.loc[(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('M'))|(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('S'))]

dfprev=dfprev.reset_index()

dfprev=dfprev.drop(columns='index')

df_diff=pd.merge(dfcurr,dfprev,how='left',indicator=True)

common_columns = df_diff.columns.intersection(dfprev.columns)
compare_df = df_diff[common_columns].eq(dfprev[common_columns])

compare_df.to_excel('comp.xlsx')

# Convert dataframe to string
df_diff = df_diff.astype(str)

def highlight_diff(data, compare):
    if type(data) != pd.DataFrame:
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if type(compare) != pd.DataFrame:
        compare = pd.DataFrame(compare)
    result = []
    for col in data.columns:
        if col in compare.columns and (data[col] != compare[col]).any():
            result.append('background-color: #DAEEF3')
        elif col not in compare.columns:
            result.append('background-color: #E4DFEC')
        else:
            result.append('background-color: white')
    return result


# Create a new workbook and add a new worksheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Write the dataframe to the worksheet
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df_diff.style.apply(highlight_diff, compare=compare_df).data, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

# Save the workbook
wb.save('Merged_style.xlsx')
```

However, I do not get an output with the style applied; no cells are highlighted in the color I want them to be highlighted in.

Edit:
I tried a different approach to highlight the cells in the excel, the function used for this approach comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102808/highlighting-the-difference-between-two-dataframes):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import pandas.io.formats.style as style

dfcurr=pd.read_excel(r'IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Current.xlsx')
dfprev=pd.read_excel(r'IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Previous.xlsx')

dfprev=dfprev.loc[(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('M'))|(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('S'))]

dfprev=dfprev.reset_index()

dfprev=dfprev.drop(columns='index')

new='background-color: #DAEEF3'
change='background-color: #E4DFEC'

df_diff=pd.merge(dfcurr,dfprev,on=['Subject','Visit','Visit Date','Site\nID','Cohort','Pathology','Clinical\nStage At\nScreening','TNMBA at\nScreening'],how='left',indicator=True)

for col in df_diff.columns:
    if '_y' in col:
        del df_diff[col]
    elif 'Unnamed: 1' in col:
        del df_diff[col]
    elif '_x' in col:
        df_diff.columns=df_diff.columns.str.rstrip('_x')

def highlight_diff(data, other, color='#DAEEF3'):
    # Define html attribute
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    # Where data != other set attribute
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)


# Set axis=None so it passes the entire frame
df_diff=df_diff.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None, other=dfprev)
print(type(df_diff))
df_diff.to_excel('Diff.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',index=0)
```

This new method provides me with an excel file where the style is applied, how can I update it to apply the color #DAEEF3 to rows in df_diff where if the Subject, Visit and Visit Date are not present in the dataframe dfprev, and apply the color #E4DFEC to cells that differs between the two files for matching Subject, Visit and Visit Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around to people I know that had to do something similar, here is the final code that produces the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#DATA FILES##################################################
#Set below to False to copy comments manually and keep the comment formatting.
copy_comments_automatically = True

#Update folderPath
folderPath = "C:/Users/G.Tielemans/OneDrive - Medpace/Documents/Innate/Script/DRA/"

#File names must match and files must be closed when running
dfcurr = pd.read_excel(folderPath + "IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Current.xlsx")
dfprev = pd.read_excel(folderPath + "IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Previous.xlsx")
#############################################################

#LOADING DATA################################################
dfprev = dfprev.loc[(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('M'))|(dfprev['Subject'].str.contains('S'))]
dfprev = dfprev.reset_index()
dfprev = dfprev.drop(columns='index')
dfprevComments = dfprev.iloc[:, 29:]
#############################################################

#NEW LINES###################################################

def highlightNewLines(linecurr):

    currSubject = linecurr["Subject"]
    currVisit = linecurr["Visit"]
    currVisitDate = linecurr["Visit Date"]

    for index, row in dfprev.iterrows():
        if currSubject == row["Subject"] and currVisit == row["Visit"] and currVisitDate == row["Visit Date"]:
            return True
    return False

dfcurr["Duplicate?"] = dfcurr.apply(lambda row: highlightNewLines(row), axis = 1)
#############################################################

#FIND UPDATES################################################
dfDupes = dfcurr[dfcurr["Duplicate?"] == True]
dfDupeslen = len(dfDupes)
#indexes of new lines to paste at bottom of file and color
indexes = dfcurr[dfcurr["Duplicate?"] == False].index

dfDupes = dfDupes.drop("Duplicate?", axis = 1)
dfDupes = dfDupes.reset_index(drop=True)
dfprev = dfprev.iloc[:,0:26]
dfprev = dfprev.reset_index(drop=True)

difference = dfDupes[dfDupes!=dfprev]


#############################################################

#ATTACH NEW FINDINGS AND PASTE MEDPACE COMMENT COLUMNS#######
newfindings = dfcurr.loc[indexes]
newfindings = newfindings.drop("Duplicate?", axis = 1)
dfDupes = pd.concat([dfDupes, newfindings])
dfDupes = dfDupes.reset_index(drop=True)
dflen = len(dfDupes)

if copy_comments_automatically:
    dfDupes = pd.concat([dfDupes, dfprevComments], axis=1)




#############################################################

#COLORING####################################################
dfDupes.to_excel(folderPath + "IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Output.xlsx", index = False)
wb = load_workbook(folderPath + "IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Output.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
fillred = PatternFill(start_color="ffc7ce", end_color="ffc7ce", fill_type = "solid")
fillblue = PatternFill(start_color="99ccff", end_color="99ccff", fill_type = "solid")


for row in range(len(difference)):
    for column in range(len(difference.columns)):
        if pd.isnull(difference.iloc[row, column]) == False:
            ws.cell(row+2, column+1).fill = fillred

for row in range(dfDupeslen, dflen):
    for column in [2,5,6]:
        ws.cell(row+2, column).fill = fillblue

wb.save(folderPath + "IPH4201P2 - DRATracker_Output.xlsx")

#############################################################
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is isn't doing anything...

`df_diff.style.apply(highlight_diff, compare=compare_df).data`

`df_diff.style` creates a `Styler` object.

`.apply` applies a function to that `Styler` for it to attach relevant HTML styling which it stores as a mapping in the `Styler` context.

`.data` the just retrieves the original `DataFrame` object that you created the `Styler` object with and it has nothing to do with those HTML styling contexts you created for the `Styler`, so you are effectively discarding them with this final `.data` addition.

`Styler` has its own `to_excel` method which interprets some of that HTML styling context and converts it to Excel cell coloring and formatting.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! If I were to get rid of the '.data', would it work then, or is there more steps to be taken to correct the issues with the code?