# Return cell difference in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code that works as expected.

From:
[Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

DF1 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.11                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     True                  " "
""")
DF2 = StringIO("""id   Name   score                    isEnrolled           Comment
111  Jack   2.17                     True                 "He was late to class"
112  Nick   1.21                     False                "Graduated"
113  Zoe    NaN                     False                "On vacation" """)


df1 = pd.read_table(DF1, sep='\s+', index_col='id')
df2 = pd.read_table(DF2, sep='\s+', index_col='id')


df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'])

df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]

def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
```

The only problem is that I do not want the first row (111) because there are no differences.

How do I select only changed rows without using the highlight_diff function?
I want to return rows 112 and 113 side-by-side without highlighting as shown by Ted's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_select = df_final.copy()
df_select.columns = df_final.columns.swaplevel()
duplicate = (df_select['First'] == df_select['Second']).all(axis=1)
df_final = df_final[~duplicate]
```

Explanation:
We create a second dataframe `df_select` to select the relevant rows (and copy `df_final` so that your original does not get changed). Its columns are swapped, so that `First` and `Second` are on the 0-th level. Then the rows you want to throw out are those where First and Second are the same. We change `df_final` to only contain the non-duplicated rows.

EDIT: If you do not want to use `df_final` at all but `df_all` instead:

```
duplicate = (df_all['First'] == df_all['Second']).drop('Comment', axis=1).all(axis=1)
result = df_all[~duplicate]
```

(I'm assuming that you do not want to check the comments, similarly to the procedure before. If you do want that, erase the `drop`.)

Comment: Correct. But is it possible to use a method of df_all instead of df_final?