# pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel: how to setup cell styling?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter, pandas-styles

I am building a diff between two dataframes and want to save them into excel (inspired by a [great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)):

```
def highlight_diff(data, color='orange'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('Original', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                    index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
```

At this point, if I look at `data_swapped.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)` in JupyterLab, it's going to be looking great - the different columns in the second set have a background.

When you try to save this to excel, it's going to fail:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('diff.xls')
data_swapped.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None).to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- packages/xlwt/Style.py in _parse_strg_to_obj(strg, obj, parse_dict, field_sep, line_sep, intro_sep, esc_char, debug)
>       636             result = parse_dict.get(section)
>       637             if result is None:
>   --> 638                 raise EasyXFCallerError('section %r is unknown' % section)
>       639             if isinstance(result, dict):
>       640                 break
>
> EasyXFCallerError: section 'fill' is unknown

I kind of figured that `xlwt` uses a different conversion for styling tags and color names and thought I'd cheat it:

```
attr = 'fore_color: light_yellow'
```

It wold remove the exception but the generated excel does not have the styling I am looking for. Is this styling approach reusable for excel at all?