# Compare two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below: I want to compare two dataframes row by row and if suppose row1 of df1 is not equal to row1 of df2 print an error

```
df1

    A     B  
0   1     3
1   2     4 
2   3     5 
3   4     6 
4   5     7 

df2

    A     B  
0   1     3
1   2     4 
2   3     5 
3   4     5
4   5     7
```

I want to print an error for row#4 because df1 has the value of 6 for variable 'B' and df1 has the value of 5

Comment: You can compare data frames using (df1 == df2).all(1), what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)?

```
df1.eq(df2)

      A      B
0  True   True
1  True   True
2  True   True
3  True  False
4  True   True
```

If you want to see the *specific* values and rows you can do this

```
df1[~df1.eq(df2)].dropna(how='all')

    A    B
3 NaN  6.0
```

Comment: I want to print an error for each row where that row has unequal value. So in that case we need to iterate through each row

Comment: no you don't iterate through a `pandas` dataframe row wise, that's not using it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I like @aws_apprentice's answer. But, since you asked to "print an error", consider also `pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal` [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html?highlight=testing%20assert_frame_equal#pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal), which will raise an `AssertionError` exception if the DataFrames are not identical and give you diagnostic output.

Answer (score 0):

you should check Andy Hayden's answer here: [Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)

what you are trying to do(print error if a row is different) may not be the best option here. which dataframe do you intend to uses as a basis for comparison and add the error column? suppose you choose df1 and compare it to df2, what if df2 has additional rows that are not present in df1; in this case there is no row in df1 to add the error msg.