# how to check content in one csv file identical, if this csv file is downloaded online

Tags: python, csv, networking, download

I download many csv files daily. Because of the performance, without opening them, I like to quickly check if these csv files are modified or changed.

I did some tests and get to know that even a csv file is not changed not modified, that is, no new lines are added into it, the "Date modified" of the file is always updated when I downloaded it. So, it means, it is not a good idea to check "Date modified" property of the csv file to tell the file modification.

any suggestion or sample code in python,

Also, If I want to get all new added lines, how could I do in python in the fastest way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To check if those files have not been changed you need to download them again, so ... just download them again :D

Comment: How are you downloading them? Depending on how that's being done (and the source of these CSV files), it _may_ be possible to do a timestamp comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would import the two .csvs you want to compare into pandas dataframes to compare them.

Check out this post: [Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)

This also describes how to show the differences.