# Improve speed of iteration over 2 lists python

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, list, loops

I have a loop that iterates over 2 lists.

`excel_data` is a list that is created from an excel spreadsheet, the new data.

`exists` is a list that is created from a sql query, the existing data.

I need to compare the two and do a SQL UPDATE if the 2nd column of the 2d list `excel_data` has a changed value for the same record from `exists`.

Currently, the loop that is taking up the time is

```
excel_data = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(20000)]
exists = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(20000)]


for i in range(0, len(excel_data)):
    for j in range(0, len(exists)):
        if exists[j][0] in excel_data[i][0] and exists[j][1] != excel_data[i][1]:
           print("")
```

Since both lists are slightly less than 20,000 in size and will only increase as time goes on, this is the equivalent of iterating 400 million times. It completes after a few minutes, but I was wondering if there is any way I can substantially reduce the number of iterations or some other shorter way to get the index of a row which has a difference in the 2nd column.

Input data is like this:

```
Sam Adams   **********@gmail.com
Sammy Adams **********@gmail.com
Samuel Adams    **********@gmail.com
Samantha Adams  **********@gmail.com
Sam Adams   **********@gmail.com
```

I am searching to see if the 2nd column, in this case an email has any sort of change for the given name in the same row.

Comment: You can make use of appropriate datastructures like sets, or make use of some framework like pandas.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. The easiest thing to do is to not iterate over the entire `exists`, and instead, create some data-structure (like a `dict` perhaps) that can map what you need to check in constant time.

Comment: What exactly don't you have to reproduce?

Comment: @donavin197300 we have essentially **nothing**. We should be able to copy and paste your [mcve] into a text-editor and run it locally and reproduce the behavior you are describing. Doing that would simply give various `NameError`s, because your code is **not complete** and therefore **not reproducible**. That is *your job* to provide when askinga question. In any case, though, your answer is not to use a `list` but a better suited data-structure, likely a `dict` in this case.

Comment: Use/research PostgreSQL FWD ([Foreign data wrappers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fdwhandler.html)) ?  Pretty sure [(third party) Excel/CSV wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) already exists and maybe might be mature enough to also use indexes on that external data..

Comment: ... also [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) also exists by the way which can be used to read CVS files on the PostgreSQL server..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes but would prefer not having to go into the Excel file and export as CSV. Ill check out the FWD and excel wrappers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With dictionaries:

```
excel_data = [[x for x in range(y, y + 2)] for y in range(20001)]
exists = [[x for x in range(y, y + 2)] for y in range(20000)]

exists[10][1] = 0  # let change at the least one element

d1 = dict(excel_data)
d2 = dict(exists)


d = {};
for k in d2:  # faster than a comprehension
    if d2[k] != d1[k]: 
        d[k] = d1[k], d2[k]

print (len(d))
```

As has been said in a comment, alternatively you can transform to sets of tuples (pairs), or for higher efficiency, frozenset, and compute set difference.

```
d = frozenset(d2.items()) - frozenset(d1.items())
```

The performance seems to be lower higher, yet the same order of magnitude  ( and no constant complexity, of course), while dictionaries are somewhat more intuitive and closer to the original version.

As said in first comments, you can use a library such as Pandas to find the diff [Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)

There are other frameworks for table slicing and dicing, e.g. petl
https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/v0.24/case_study_1.html

PS Fun fact. Set version is slower.More after executing set version the following commands run slower until garbage is collected.

Comment: How would you get the value of both columns, right now it only gives output for column 1

Comment: I included the columns values

Comment: No  clue why the downvote when this method is exponentially faster... anyways I will look for pandas, I had simply manually parsed the xlsx with openpyxl, probably not the best option and I can now see why.

Comment: Thanks, yet it is only polynomial faster so to say from you code.