# two dataframe fet difference ( numpy )

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
d1 = df1.filter(items=['col_a']) # len(d1) = 900
d2 = df.filter(items=['col_a']) # len(d2) = 920

d1 ---------->
    col_a
0   802584
1   408852
2   408311
3   409633
4   801848
5   123123
6   232333

d2 ---------->
    col_a
0   802584
1   408852
2   408311
3   409633
4   801848
```

col_a is integer value and I want to compare between d1 and d2 to extract differences.

How can I get a new dataframe that includes only 20 values for col_a?

In this situation, I want to get

```
new_df ----->
     col_a
0    123123
1    232333
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Unfortunately, your question is not clear enough, you can add Input and expected outputs as well to clarify.

Comment: @FadingOrigami Thank you for concerning, I updated what I exactly want to get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side)

Comment: @InyoungKim In my case, shape is different.

Comment: Try answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902170/8471995) question. `df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna(how = 'all')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and negation `(~)`:

```
In [1278]: d1[~d1.col_a.isin(d2.col_a)]
Out[1278]: 
    col_a
5  123123
6  232333
```

Comment: A question. Can `negation (~)` all python? Or is it `pandas` only?

Comment: Python `not` operator is `!`. Pandas `~` is mostly like `not in` operator in `SQL`.

Comment: it shows empty in my code but looks correct in your code.
both type integer64. I'll check data.
@InyoungKim Your answer shows same like d1

Comment: I tested my code on the sample you provided. Works fine for me. Please make sure you are running my exact command.

Comment: Okay. If you proved I'll use your code to test my data.
Thank you so much