# how to compare two dataframes and return a new dataframe with only the records that have changed

Tags: python, pandas

I want to build a python script that will compare two pandas dataframes and create a new `df` that I can use to update my sql table. I create `df1` by reading the existing table. I create `df2` by reading the new data through an API call. I want to isolate changed lines and update the SQL table with the new values.

I have attempted to compare through an outer merge, but I need help returning the dataframe with only records with a different value in any field.

Here is my example `df1`:

[image]

Here is my example `df2`:

[image]

My desired output:

[image]

This function returns the entire dataframe and isn't working as expected:

```
def compare_dataframes(df1, df2, pk_col):
    # Merge the two dataframes on the primary key column
    df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=pk_col, how='outer', suffixes=('_old', '_new'))

    # Identify the rows that are different between the two dataframes
    df_diff = df_merged[df_merged.isna().any(axis=1)]

    # Drop the columns from the old dataframe and rename the columns from the new dataframe
    df_diff = df_diff.drop(columns=[col for col in df_diff.columns if col.endswith('_old')])
    df_diff = df_diff.rename(columns={col: col.replace('_new', '') for col in df_diff.columns})

    return df_diff
```

Comment: please provide reproducible inputs, images are not accepted

Comment: @mozway it's okay, i figured it out with insanity's help.

Comment: It doesn't make it more acceptable, keep in mind that this site is not only to help you but also to have a nice database of Q/A for everyone. By not providing a correct reproducible example you reduce the accessibility for some of the future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to concatenate the 2 dataframes and then remove duplicates as shown below:

```
dict = {1:df1,2:df2}
df=pd.concat(dict)
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

As provided in answer to similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42649293/21442120

```
import sys 
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

DF1 = StringIO("""
id,field1,field2,field3,field4
0,x,y,,b
1,x,,,
2,x,y,z,
3,x,y,z,b
4,x,y,,b""")

DF2 = StringIO("""
id,field1,field2,field3,field4
0,x,y,,b
1,x,,a,
2,x,y,z,
3,x,y,z,b
4,x,y,a,b
""")

df1 = pd.read_table(DF1, sep=',', index_col='id')
df2 = pd.read_table(DF2, sep=',', index_col='id')

# STEP 1
dictionary = {1:df1,2:df2}
df=pd.concat(dictionary)
df3 = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index()

# STEP 2
df4 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')
df4 = df4.drop('level_0', axis=1)
df4.head()
```

Gives Output as Desired:

```
id  field1  field2  field3  field4
1   1   x   NaN a   NaN
2   4   x   y   a   b
```

Comment: thank you, this is getting me closer. now that I have a df with both lines from each df, i'm struggling with isolating just the lines from the second df. any thoughts?

Comment: actually, i figured it out, the method you suggested returns a multi-index df, I can filter using `loc[2]` which are the record that belongs the dict key '2'

Comment: I have edited the answer which makes it possible in two steps exactly as you want; it looks like a hack and i am sure there are better ways to do it.

Comment: for 'step 2' i went with: `df = df.loc[2]`