# Compare two different dataframes and bring the highlighted differences on a new sheet

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Compare two different dataframes and bring the highlighted differences on a new sheet
My data frames are:
df1

[image]

df2
[image]

Expected output in three different sheets

Sheet1 Overall data
[image]

Sheet 2 - ESPID with ESPStandard mismatch
[image]

Sheet 3 - ESPID with Last_match mismatch
[image]

My lookup value is always with ESPID of DF1 with StarID of DF2 and bring the corresponding columns.

The answer posted by Ted Petrou's is very closer [Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side), however my scenario is slightly different

1. My column names are different in both the data frames
2. Is there a way to bring each differences to a separate Sheet on an excel?

   df_all = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Starid'),
   df2.set_index('ESPID')],

   ```
           axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'])
   ```

   df_all

   df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]

   df_final

   def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):

   attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

   other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)

   return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
   index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

   df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)

   df_final.to_excel('Output.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True)

[Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/compare-two-dataframes-and-output-their-differences-side-by-side)